# How to get remote ip from `twisted.web._newclient.Response` instance

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web

I have a code, which make request to web-site (request by hostname, for example - www.google.com). Remote host send a response. **How can I get IP of the host, which sent a response?**

***PS***

I'm using [twisted web client](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html)

***PS2***

**[Feature request](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/6741)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present, there is no way.  [`Agent`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.client.Agent.html) itself doesn't expose this information, nor an API for discovering this information.  Neither does the [`IResponse`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.iweb.IResponse.html) provider which you get back from the `Deferred` returned by `Agent.request`.

This sounds like a good feature request to file at http://twistedmatrix.com/trac :)